# Facebook android sdk: change animation during login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have an activity contains facebook login button, and when login is done, new activity is launched. 
I've see that when i login, a new blank activity (maybe the facebook LoginActivity) is launched and a spinner is showed. When login is done, that activity end and focus return for a moment to my activity contains facebook button login before start new activity. Could i change behavior during login?
I would only show a spinner inside current Activity